# Stack Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, stack

This is my first template implementation. I'm trying to learn C++ and Algorithms. Any constructive criticism on code quality, readability is welcome. Everyone has their own style, but there are certain rules which all good programmers should follow. Kindly remark as to if I have followed those and what rules are missing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl;
using std::nothrow; using std::size_t;

template<typename T> class Stack {
 public:
  // constructor for class
  Stack() { count = 0;
            last = NULL; }
  // destructor for class
  ~Stack() {  if (count > 0) Clr(); }
  // push item at last of stack
  void Push(T item);
  // pop item from last of stack
  T Pop();
  // get size of stack
  size_t Size();
  void Clr();       // delete all the elements
  // print all the elements
  void Print();
 private:
  // the stack will store elements in the form of a linked list
  struct Node {
    T value;
    Node* next;
  };
  Node* last;   // last points to the last item of the stack
  size_t count;    // number of elements in stack
};
/*
Check for memory allocation first. If memory allocated, then Push element in
the stack. 
 */
template<typename T> void Stack<T>::Push(T item) {
  Node* node = new (nothrow) Node;
  if (node == NULL) {
    cout << "Memory allocation failed " << endl;
    return;
  } else {
    node->value = item;
    if (count == 0) {
      node->next = NULL;
      last = node;
      ++count;
    } else {
      node->next = last;
      last = node;
      ++count;
    }
  }
}
/*
Delete the elements
 */
template<typename T> void Stack<T>::Clr() {
  Node* node = last;
  while (count != 0) {
    Node* tempnode = node;
    node = node->next;
    delete tempnode;
    --count;
  }
}
/*
Pop the last element of the stack and return it
 */
template<typename T> T Stack<T>::Pop() {
  if (count == 0) {
    cout << "No element to delete" << endl;
    return (T)0;
  } else {
    Node* node = last;
    T tempval = node->value;
    last = node->next;
    delete(node);
    --count;
    return tempval;
  }
}
/*
Print all the elements
 */
template<typename T> void Stack<T>::Print() {
  if (count == 0) {
    cout << "No elements to print" << endl;
    return;
  } else {
    cout << "Printing from top of the Stack to Bottom" << endl;
    Node* node = last;
    while (node != NULL) {
      cout << node->value << "->";
      node = node->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}
/*
Get the size of the Stack
 */
template<typename T> size_t Stack<T>::Size() {
  return count;
}
/*
Main function
 */
int main() {
  Stack<int> s;
  s.Push(12);
  s.Push(10);
  s.Push(23);
  s.Push(34);
  cout << "The value Popped from the Stack: " << s.Pop() << endl;
  s.Print();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: **NEVER** do this `using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl;` in a header file. You will change the meaning of my code just because I include your header file. That is really bad and will get your code banned from projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `NULL` versus `nullptr`

You shouldn't be using `NULL`, as you did in various places, like here:

> ```
> node->next = NULL;
> ```

`NULL` is deprecated, and you should be using `nullptr`, like this:

```
node->next = nullptr;
```

If this is legacy code, and you need to support users running old compilers that date to before C++11, you should keep using `NULL`.

---

## `std::endl` versus `"\n"`

Rather than using `std::endl`, you should just suffix this onto the end of any `std::cout` statements:

```
<< "\n";
```

You should be doing this unless you're very sure that you want to flush the output buffer each time you run `std::cout`. **If** you do need to flush the output buffer, then you should keep using `std::endl`.

---

## Nitpicks

There are a fair amount of things that I want to pick at here, so bear with me.

- You should remove all the `using` statements at the top of your code. By removing the prefix of `std::` on some of it's members, your code loses clarity. The only time it's really appropriate to use a namespace, or namespace members is when you have a really deep nested namespace, like `foo::bar::baz::barbaz::blah`.
- Secondly, there are a lot of useless comments. For example, the comment by the function signature for `Clr`, is not really needed. If you give `Clr` a better name, like `removeAll`, the need for the comment vanishes. This applies to many other comments as well.
- Finally, the `Stack` class should have a `toString` method, which should return a `std::string`-representation of the stack.

Comment: `std::cout << '\n';` should do I.e. char should do. Also going with [the standard function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), it should be `std::to_string`.

Answer (score 3):

### Use Virtual destructors

This for no other reason than polymorphism, so if you are not planning on having another class inherit from this one, ignore the next little bit. Example:

```
class base {};
class derived : public base {
    public:
    ~derived() {}
};

int main() {
    base* b = new derived();
    delete b; // this is undefined unless base defines a destructor that is virtual
}
```

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)

### Constructors should be declared "explicit"

The reason for doing this is because it is actually possible in C++ to do something like this:

```
class myclass {
    int value;
    public:
    myclass(int v) : value(v) {}
};

int main() {
    myclass c = 5;
    return 0;
}
```

And the compiler will not even complain. However, if you had declared your constructor like this:

```
explicit myclass(int v) : value(v) {}
```

Then the above code would have resulted in a compiler error.

### Printing error messages is for debugging

This one might be debatable but you should *throw an exception* rather than printing an error message when something unexpected has happend.

I call this the `fail-fast` pattern. In essence, you don't want the person reusing your class to keep using it the wrong way and only end up realising this when the code has developed into an application. No! You want to alert them immediately something goes wrong; And the way to do this is not by printing nice error messages to standard output, but rather to throw an exception and halt program execution until the error has been fixed.

#### Misc.

- Your `Print` function should be able to print not just to standard output but also to some other output stream the user wants. This means that it should take an `std::ostream` object as parameter and use that instead of `std::cout`
- Your `Clr` function should use `Pop` for deleting items. This reduces the amount of stress you face if you end up finding a fault with the way `Clr` works
- Replace all `if (count == 0)` or `if (count != 0)` statements with a function called `isEmpty()` which returns the value of that expression

Answer (score 2):

There are already two reviews with many good points, [one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/103832) by [Ethan Bierlein](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/u/53251) and a [second](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/103834) by [Smac89](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/u/29131).
I will explicitly mention *all* their recommendations, criticizing, emphasizing and putting them into context as I go.

1. First, the load of distracting comment should be contained and severely pruned back.
   Ethan recommends reducing the need for comments by proper naming, which is sound advice, and deserves more emphasis.
   You already did much of that, but you restate even the blindingly obvious in comments.
   I recommend reading about [DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), or as Jeff calls this aspect of it, [Coding Without Comments](http://blog.codinghorror.com/coding-without-comments/).
2. If there are any comparable interfaces already, choose one and conform to it as best you can. Doing so enables code-reuse and minimizes confusion and neccessary documentation. In your case, look at the standard containers, specifically [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack).
   For example, `Size()` should be `size()` and accompanied by `empty()`. `Pop` and `Push` should be lowercase.
3. Ethan's praise for `nullptr` over `NULL` is sound advice, because even though `NULL` is conceptually a pointer of unknown type (and thus should be the defined as `nullptr`), it [could also be defined as a number](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL) for backwards-compatibility.
   Still, `NULL` isn't deprecated, `nullptr` doesn't exist pre-C++11, and if your C++ code shall also be valid C++/CLI code, using `nullptr` [will lead to much fun in the minecraft sense](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj651642.aspx).
4. Ethan is death on using `using`, but there's some nuance to it.

   While in an implementation-file, pulling in some symbols from other namespaces (or in certain cases even *all* symbols from select namespaces, read https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721 for when it isn't) is useful to avoid being needlessly long-winded and repetitive, in header-files (https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021), introducing any symbol you don't *have* to (which is *not* part of your interface) courts the dangers of inadvertent dependencies and breakage.
5. You should consider putting your code into your own namespace to avoid future clashes.

   You might even want to [use an inline-namespace for versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016220/what-are-inline-namespaces-for).
6. Ethan's recommendation for `std::endl` versus `\n`, while basically sound, should actually be: Eschew explicit flushing unless you need it to ensure timely output.
7. You could provide an iterator-interface to get all elements, though that's not customary for a stack. [Mutable ForwaddIterator is the concept it should fulfill.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator)
   The advantages are access to standard algorithms and general ability to reduce coupling.
8. If you want to allow conversion to `std::string` as Ethan advocates, use a free [`to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)-function.
   You can use the iterator-interface for it if you implemented that, or it must be a friend-function. Not much use outside debugging.
9. As Smac89 says, if you supply a `Print`-function it accept a user-supplied `std::ostream` (though you can (and maybe should) certainly provide a default-argument of `std::cout`).
   It can be implemented in terms of `to_string`, and all the other remarks I made for that apply too.
10. Smac's point on virtual destructory isn't really germane to your current class, though should be kept in mind.

    Use a virtual destructor if the class has any other virtual members (functions, variables and bases, inherited or direct), or you want to destroy polymorphically, neither of which applies to you.
    In general, avoid virtual members because they add conceptual complexity (adding a contract about when it must be called, this does not strictly apply to the destructor) and runtime overhead.
11. Never silently keep going at an error, like failure to allocate neccessary memory.
    Iff there's internal corruption or there's no chance the caller might be able to recover, abort the program (and try to log details to logfile/stderror, *never* to standard output).
    Otherwise, but only if the error is expected, your function should return an error-code.
    Exceptions are the preferred way though.
12. Your code violates [the rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)), the implicit copy-/move- constructors and assignment-operators are wrong.

    Either disable them with `=delete`, or implement them yourself.
13. You should put the pointer first in `struct Node` to enable more identical-code-folding.
14. Your stack is not exception-safe, it needlessly assumes copying or assigning a `T` can never throw. Correct that.

    Using `std::unique_ptr` where possible makes that easy.

---

Now going into the details of some of your functions:

1. `Push`: You have a useless if-else-statement in there:

   ```
   template<typename T> void Stack<T>::push(T item) {
       auto x = make_unique<Node>{last, std::move(T)};
       ++count;
       last = x.release();
   }
   ```
2. `Clr`: You shouldn't constantly update the member-variables, it should be called `clear`, otherwise ok.
3. `Pop`: Underflow should be a fatal error. Also, if you want a default-element, better use `T()`.